# Change data status for all elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the first function, an item is marked read or unread by clicking the `.activity__button`. The next function is to change the status of all of the items to `read`.

Why isn't the function iterating over each `item` and `button`?

```
var button = $(".activity__button");
var item = $(".activity__item");
```

When I press the `button` to change the status to `read`, nothing happens. Additionally, how do you handle a second click of the `button` to change all back to `unread`?

```js
$(".activity__button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var icon = $(this).find("svg");
  var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
  if (status === "read") {
    $(this)
      .removeClass("activity__button--read")
      .attr("data-status", "unread");
    icon.attr("data-icon", "envelope");
    $(this)
      .closest(".activity__item")
      .removeClass("activity__item--read")
      .attr("data-status", "unread");
  } else {
    $(this)
      .addClass("activity__button--read")
      .attr("data-status", "read");
    icon.attr("data-icon", "envelope-open");
    $(this)
      .closest(".activity__item")
      .addClass("activity__item--read")
      .attr("data-status", "read");
  }
});
$(".section").on("click", ".mark", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var button = $(".activity__button");
  var item = $(".activity__item");
  var icon = button.find("svg");
  var status = button.attr("data-status");
  if (status === "unread") {
    button.addClass("activity__button--read").attr("data-status", "read");
    icon.attr("data-icon", "envelope-open");
    item.addClass("activity__item--read").attr("data-status", "read");
  }
});
```

```css
.activity__item {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.activity__button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.activity__button svg {
  color: #f8971d;
}

.activity__button.activity__button--read svg {
  color: #47a877;
}

.activity__item--read {
  background: #fafafa !important;
}

button {
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class "section">
  <button class="mark">Mark as Read</button>
  <div>
    <div class="activity__item">
      <div class="activity__button" data-status="unread"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity__item">
      <div class="activity__button" data-status="unread"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="activity__item activity__item--read">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--read" data-status="read">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity__item">
      <div class="activity__button" data-status="unread">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $(".element").off().on('click', function() { }); - this successfully prevent from running multiple times. For data-*name u can use $(".element").data('name') for data-name. And try to make click events for an element, not whole section ex. $(". activity__item").off().on('click', function() { if($(this).hasClass('mark') { ...code...} } ); and then use child for finding whatever child u need to set.

To change all elements use jquery each, or simple $(".element").data('name', 'other value');

Comment: @ Grzegorz Miśkiewicz Are you able to provide a working answer?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v765j43s/ are mean of something like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example (with other classes)

```
var open = 'fas fa-envelope-open';
var close = 'fas fa-envelope';

$(".activity__button").off().on('click', function() {
    var status = $(this).data('status');
    if( status == 'unread' ) {
        $(this).data('status', 'read').empty().html('<i class="' + open + '"></i>').addClass('activity__button--read');
        $(this).parent().addClass('activity__item--read');
    } else {
        $(this).data('status', 'unread').empty().html('<i class="' + close + '"></i>').removeClass('activity__button--read');
        $(this).parent().removeClass('activity__item--read');
    }
});

$('.mark').off().on('click', function() {
    $(".activity__button").each( function() {
    $(this).data('status', 'read').empty().html('<i class="' + open + '"></i>').addClass('activity__button--read');
    $(this).parent().addClass('activity__item--read');
  });
});
```

See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8yk9a7rn/

Comment: Yes but the icon color and the background of the item change depending on the state. 

.activity__button.activity__button--read svg {
  color: #47a877;
}

.activity__item--read {
  background: #fafafa !important;
}

Comment: I've edited this code - and adding those colors few minutes ago :-)

Comment: Nice, it's working good. Is there a way to have the second click of the `button` mark all of the items back to `read`?

Comment: yes - read status of this element, and use it like in activity__button way - also u can, change name from mark read, to unmark: https://jsfiddle.net/8yk9a7rn/2/

Comment: Thanks for the update. It functions nicely except you have to click the envelope twice to mark as `read` again after you toggle the `button`. Does the code require ` e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: added border to real clickable area - in this area works ok like it should. e.stopPropagation and preventDefault is not required, but u can use it.

Comment: Sorry its late and I'm going sleep now. Check jsfiddle - there was little mistake, so double click was needed. I repair this. Your answer is up there, so vote up and have a good "coding" night or day - wherever u are ;-)